# Requests for electronic versions of books

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Should we allow requests for electronic versions of books such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/33681/need-a-copy-of-graph-theory-by-balakrishnan)? While sometimes there may be legit copies out there, most of the time the books are copyrighted and we shouldn't post links to pirate copies or sites here.

Comment: Here's an [older thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/529/to-what-extent-should-copyrighted-material-be-made-available-on-math-se) concerning these issues.

Comment: @Theo, thanks .

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Notwithstanding questions of copyright, I see no mathematical content in a plea to acquire a copy of some book/article; such requests are then outside this site's scope.